# How can I select this span class element using Selenium 3?

Tags: html, class, element

How can I select this span class element using Selenium 3?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just copy xpath of element using browser dev tools (F12)

Comment: Hi, Sir thank you for your comment. I tried using abs xpath it does not work. It work using linkTest: 
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Process Level"));
        builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();